# Teamcity, build maven project with parent dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, teamcity, pom.xml

I've 1 project with one subproject in my teamcity server. The subproject has the pom.xml file that references parent project.

This is the pom.xml of the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>it.company.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>MyProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <modules>
    <module>Foo</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

This is the pom.xml of the subproject:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>it.company.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Foo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>subproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run the maven build from my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) on my subproject, all works fine. Also when I run maven build on the parent project all works fine.

When I run **build agent** (configured to run pom.xml) from TeamCity server on my subproject it doesn't work, and I've the following errors:

```
[Step 1/1] Error reading Maven project: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact it.company.project:MyProject:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13
.
[14:08:12][Step 1/1] TeamCity is unable to read Maven project. Some features may be unavailable
```

When I run **build agent** (configured to run pom.xml) from TeamCity server on my parent project it doesn't work, and I've the following errors:

```
An error occurred during collecting Maven project information: File not found in any VCS root: subproject/pom.xml.
```

My subproject build configurations:

[image]

What's wrong?

---

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us more info about how you're running build agent

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas what do you like to know?
To run the build I only press the run button near the subproject build.

Comment: have a look at the maven repository for the teamcity local user and check the parent pom has been installed there. If not that could be an issue. run "mvn clean install" on the parent first

Comment: @Josh I've tried to run `mvn clean install` on the parent project, but I get the following error: `An error occurred during collecting Maven project information: File not found in any VCS root: subproject/pom.xml.`

Comment: You have a module referenced from your parent called Foo, but your subproject isn't this module. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Also, you have your java source directory marked as a resource directory, which seems very odd (bordering on the weird).

Comment: And you're using a five year old version of junit...

Comment: @EngineerDollery it's not my project, I've to maintain only! I've edited my question, now the parent project reference the correct subproject (Foo).

Comment: Right, then to build `Foo` you should be running the build at the parent level with `-pl Foo -am`. You shouldn't really be running maven in directly in the submodules.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Can I pass a properties to `<relativePath>` tag ?

Comment: Yes you can, via a property placeholder ${...} and an environment variable, but why would you want to do that? You should aim for a simple build that sticks with convention and not try anything fancy -- it always leads to unnecessary pain.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I know that can I use property, but that property is ignored in `relativePath`.